# UIApplication openURL: check for an app before opening?

Tags: nsurl, uiapplication, url-scheme

Has something changed recently in iOS? I've been able to call the following in the past:

```
BOOL twitter = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=username"]];
if (twitter) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=username"]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/username"]];
}
```

What this would do is basically check whether the device responds to the URL (if the app is installed or not) and open the app if it's installed, otherwise do `else`

When I test on my device (iPhone 4, 4.3.2) it opens the Twitter app when creating the BOOL.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:yourURL];
```