# Launch Facebook app from my app and make it open a profile which is not mine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, twitter

I am working on an app where I need to put a button that will redirect users to a certain Facebook page. Normally tapping on this button should open the profile in the Facebook app or in the navigator if Facebook is not installed. Plus I would like to do the same thing with a twitter page.

I would like like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all comes down to the custom url schemes.  Facbook's is `fb://` so if you were to open `fb://profile/zuck` Mobile Safari would kick you over to the Facebook app and load Mark Zuckerbergs profile page.  There currently is a bug in the new Facebook app preventing it from loading profiles correctly.

To check if the user's device can respond to a URL scheme check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683002/uiapplication-openurl-check-for-an-app-before-opening).

EDIT::

As far as Twitter you may want to check for a few different Twitter clients like `twitter://` or `tweetbot://` before kicking the user over to `https://twitter.com/#!/<# User Name #>`

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon @SkylarSch's answer, this will try to open the page in the native Facebook app first, otherwise it will open it in Mobile Safari:

```
NSURL *fbNativeAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/yourPageIDHere"];

// Check to make sure URL can be opened on device (whether the user has the Facebook app installed)
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbNativeAppURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbNativeAppURL];
}
// Otherwise, just open it in the browser
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/yourPageIDHere"]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can open it by getting Facebook id of that profile. So you can find Facebook id as :
URL https://www.facebook.com/pageName 
Now, go to: http://findmyfacebookid.com Paste your URL, get Facebook id, and then make url as @"fb://profile/profileID"

IT WORKED FOR ME!

Answer (score 1):

{edit}I see what you mean{/edit}

The Facebook iPhone app registers as a URL handler for the `fb://` prefix. I'm not sure if this is working in all versions, but i believe clicking a link to `fb://profile/{page or profile id}` will open the profile in the iphone app (if installed).

I found that on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app) which was accurate as of version 3.4 (it's currently on 4.0 but i imagine most of those are still valid)

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, my english is not good. The thing is i need to make an iOS app wich can open a facebook profile wich is not the local user profile (for example coca cola page on facebook). And i want that profiel page to open in the facebook app and not in the safari navigator. I am not sure if it is possible, i've never an app doing that. Thanks a lot for your answer. and sorry again for the post clarity.